# Testing a Callable via ApexMocks

Tags: mock, callable

I have a trigger that calls a Callable class when a status is changed. I want to verify that the call function is called with the correct argument and so I tried mocking Callable using fflib_ApexMocks. However I am getting error below:

> Test.createStub() can only be called with classes in the current namespace.

Is there a way to mock the Callable class for unit testing?

Comment: welcome to SFSE!  Please see [ask] on getting the most from the Community. We're going to need to see some specifics here to answer this -- the class/method being mocked and your testmethod. Use [edit]

Comment: The link helped me figure it out. Callable interface is in System namespace so it is not covered by the Stub API.